# Latest update disabled all internet access

Tags: networking, 22.04, internet, ethernet

I updated yesterday, and when I started my computer today the internet was not working.  It's working on both my phone and my work laptop, so I know it's not a problem with the network itself.

When trying to connect to my wifi the access box where I type my password is gone within a second so that's no help.

I tried changing the kernel in grub when I restarted but it did not help.

`uname -r` : `5.15.0-52-generic` | `5.15.0-53-generic` (after restart, did not change default kernel)

```
lspci | egrep -o --color 'network|ethernet':
06:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller (rev 05)
```

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Edit:
I tried changing managed=false to true under [ifupdown] in the network manager.

Edit #2:
I tried removing wireguard which said it was connected when typing nmcli

Both my wired and wireless connections are still failing.

I "fixed" it with a workaround. I connected to my wireless network as a hidden network. My wired connection is still broken but at least I have a connection.

Comment: You are probably using NetworkManager. Take a look at `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`. Does it say 'managed=false' somewhere? Then change it to "true" and restart NetworkManager. It happens (rarely but annoyingly) that an update changes that to false.

Comment: I tried doing that (it did say managed=false under [ifupdown] and I changed it to true, then I restarted my computer and it still does not work.

Comment: The reason I restarted my computer was because I ran:
sudo service network-manager restart
Failed to restart network-manager.service: Unit network-manager.service not found.
(Was not allowed to edit my comment)

Comment: In 22.04 that should be `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`.

Comment: This did not work either

Comment: I "fixed" it with a workaround. I connected to my wireless network as a hidden network. My wired connection is still broken but at least I have a connection.

Comment: If someone has any ideas I'd be more than willing to try them.